# javascript google map geolocalisation

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a map and I would like center it on the position of the client but it doesn't work on firefox and on chrome it centers on a wrong position.

My code is :

```
var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.483265, 2.391586),
zoom: 5,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
}
else
alert("'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation HTML5.'");

function successCallback(position){
map.setZoom(9);
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
}; 

function errorCallback(error){
switch(error.code){
  case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
    alert("The user is not allowed access to its position");
    break;     
  case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
    alert("The location of the user could not be determined");
    break;
  case error.TIMEOUT:
    alert("The service did not respond in time");
    break;
  }
};
```

Comment: on which kind of hardware do you try this(1. are you connected via WIFI or 2. does the device have a GPS-sensor)?

Comment: on a pc with wifi connection without gps

Comment: with the connection of my smartphone I get "The location of the user could not be determined" on chrome and it doesn't work on firefox (without message)

Comment: where do you live? is your neighborhood available in google-maps-streetview?

Comment: In france. Yes, my neighborhood is available in google streetview.

Comment: sorry, then I have no idea :(